# How to calculate GMD and GMR?

Tags: power-supply, power, mains, three-phase, inductance

[image]

The above image is from my class notes. I am not able to understand the concept of GMD and GMR calculation.

While practicing, I came across the below problem

[image]

Now I am not able to understand how the above formulae can be used to solve this problem. Please help me with this concept.

**EDIT 1:** I was expecting the solution to be like

Taking 1 as a phase and 2,3 as another phase

Mutual GMD = (D12 x D13)^(1/2) = (2 x 4)^(1/2) = 2.828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For section 1
Mutual GMD = (Dab x Dbc x Dca)^(1/3) = (2x2x4) = 2.5198m

No need to calculate for section 2 and 3 because it will be same as section 1

Mutual GMD = Deq = 2.5198m